# migrate createCipher et createCipheriv

Tags: node.js, cryptojs

I just moved to node 12.13 and I have some issue with `crypto.createDecipher` and `crypto.createCipher`

First I have deprecation warnings when I am using the two functions.

```js
const encodeString = (value, password) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const cipher = crypto.createCipher("aes192", password);
    let encrypted = "";
    cipher.on("readable", () => {
      const data = cipher.read();
      if (data) encrypted += data.toString("hex");
    });
    cipher.on("end", () => resolve(encrypted));

    cipher.write(value);
    cipher.end();
  });

const decodeString = (encrypted, password) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipher("aes192", password);
    let decrypted = "";
    decipher.on("readable", () => {
      const data = decipher.read();
      if (data) decrypted += data.toString("utf8");
    });
    decipher.on("end", () => resolve(decrypted));

    decipher.write(encrypted, "hex");
    decipher.end();
  });

data()
  .then(data => {
    console.log("final", data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("final err", err);
  });
```

I am looking for a way to migrate to `createCipheriv` and `createDecipheriv` but I can not find how to convert my password into key and iv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

find below way to generate key and IV & methods for implementations

```
const keyBytes: Buffer = Buffer.from(password, 'base64');
  // Generates 16 byte cryptographically strong pseudo-random data as IV
  // https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback
  const ivBytes: Buffer = crypto.randomBytes(16);
  const ivText: string = ivBytes.toString('base64');
```

encrypt

```
export function encryptString(plainText: string, secret: string): string {
    if (!plainText || plainText.length === 0) {
        return plainText;
    }
    if (!secret || secret.length === 0) {
        throw new Error('you must pass a secret');
    }
    const keyBytes: Buffer = Buffer.from(secret, 'base64');
    // Generates 16 byte cryptographically strong pseudo-random data as IV
    // https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback
    const ivBytes: Buffer = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    const ivText: string = ivBytes.toString('base64');
    // encrypt using aes256 iv + key + plainText = encryptedText
    const cipher: crypto.Cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', keyBytes, ivBytes);
    let encryptedValue: string = cipher.update(plainText, 'utf8', 'base64');
    encryptedValue += cipher.final('base64');
    // store base64(ivBytes)!base64(encryptedValue)
    return `${ ivText }!${ encryptedValue }`;
}
```

decrypt

```
    export function decryptString(encryptedValue: string, secret: string):string {

        if (!encryptedValue || encryptedValue.length === 0) {
        return encryptedValue;
      }

    if (!secret || secret.length === 0) {
        throw new Error('you must pass a secret');
    }

     const parts: string[] = encryptedValue.split('!');
    if (parts.length !== 2) {
        throw new Error('The encrypted value is not a valid format');
    }
    const ivText: string = parts[0];
    const encryptedText: string = parts[1];
    const ivBytes: Buffer = Buffer.from(ivText, 'base64');
    const keyBytes: Buffer = Buffer.from(secret, 'base64');

    if (ivBytes.length !== 16) {
        throw new Error('The encrypted value is not a valid format');
    }

    if (keyBytes.length !== 32) {
        throw new Error('The secret is not valid format');
    }

    // decrypt using aes256 iv + key + encryptedText = decryptedText
    const decipher: crypto.Decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', keyBytes, ivBytes);
    let value: string = decipher.update(encryptedText, 'base64', 'utf8');
    value += decipher.final('utf8');    
    return value;}
```